# getting Unable to resolve action `my_repo/s3-sync-action@v0.5.1`, repository not found

Tags: github, amazon-s3, github-actions

I am not a DevOps expert so not sure what this means exactly, I have a GitHub actions pipeline, there when I am trying to run the pipeline I get the above error. My code is as below

Main.yml

```
  deploy_dev: 
    name: deploy_dev
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: some-image
    needs: build-dev
    steps: 
        - 
         name: "Checkout Repo"
         uses: actions/checkout@v2
       
        - 
         name: artifacts
         uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
         with: 
           name: "upload artifacts"
           path: build/
    

   #  S3 Deployment
        - 
          name: S3 Deployment
          uses:  my_repo/s3-sync-action@v0.5.1
          with:
           args: --acl public-read --follow-symlinks --delete  
          env:
           AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_DEV}}
           AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_DEV }}
           AWS_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.BUCKET_NAME_DEV }}
           DISTRIBUTION: ${{ secrets.CDN_DISTRIBUTN_ID_DEV }}
```

Any idea how i can fix this error ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have forked the `s3-sync-action` but maybe, in your repo, you don't have the `v0.5.1` tag. So I would suggest to use `main` or `master` as reference (depending of your repo's config) like:

```
   #  S3 Deployment
        - 
          name: S3 Deployment
          uses:  my_repo/s3-sync-action@main
```